# Let $X$ be a topological vector space. If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, so is $\overline{Y}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I was reading *Functional Analysis* by Rudin. There was a theorem as mentioned below:

> Let $X$ be a topological vector space. If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, so is $\overline{Y}$.

While proving it at one point he mentioned something like this :

> By the proposition in Section 1.7, $\alpha \overline{Y} = \overline{\alpha Y}$.

The proposition 1.7 was :

> $T_a$ and $M_{\lambda}$, where $T_a(x) = a+x$, for a fixed $a\in X$ and $M_{\lambda}(x) = \lambda x$, for a fixed scalar $\lambda$ be two operators on $x$, are homomorphism of $X$ onto $X$.

But when I'm trying to prove $\alpha \overline{Y} = \overline{\alpha Y}$. analytically, I can't do it at all. Can I get some help?

Comment: For any  homeomorphism $\theta$,closure of $\theta(Y)$ is same as $\theta (\overline Y)$.

Comment: Right. I completely forgot that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T_{\alpha}(x)=\alpha x$ is a Homeomorphism. (see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_iff_Image_of_Closure_equals_Closure_of_Image))

Hence $$T_{\alpha}(\overline{A})=\overline{{T_{\alpha}(A)}} $$

implies $\alpha\overline{A}=\overline{\alpha A}$

Comment: How did I miss it!!!! Thank you, I couldn't even use the homeomorphism fact.